# MacBook not responsive when woken within the second it went to sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Air 11" mid 2013 with all the updates. When the screen gets turned off and I try to wake it up in the very same second by touching the touch-pad or pressing a key, it will get stuck and I need to reboot it.

I've observed the same behavior on a friend's MacBook Air 13" - don't know since when she has it though.

Is it a bug in Mavericks? Anybody else observed this kind of behavior? I couldn't find anything about it, maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing.

**Update:**

I've tried as suggested in the comments, after a fresh start, with the following results:

- closing the lid completely, waiting for a second and opening it -> **everything is fine**
- put down the lid just so that the screen is turned off (not closed) and opening it right away, screen and keyboard are lighten up again, but the screen is black, waiting for a minute doesn't change anything and closing the lid again doesn't put my laptop to sleep anymore -> **computer stays non responsive**

**Update 2:**

My MacBook Air 11" mid 2013 is equipped with:

- CPU: Core i7
- RAM: 8GB
- SSD: 256GB

Regarding the console output, I couldn't file any entry which signalises a suspension of the laptop.

I did the experiment once the clock changed to 12:17 and waited from there for another minute before I restarted the laptop and this is the logs I have during that time period (taken from "All Messages":

```
22/02/14 12:16:22,415 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100041 created
22/02/14 12:16:23,025 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100043 created
22/02/14 12:16:23,033 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Killing auth hosts
22/02/14 12:16:23,033 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100041 destroyed
22/02/14 12:18:40,000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1393067920 0
22/02/14 12:18:43,000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

When closing the lid totally and successfully waking the laptop up, I got the following logs (again I closed the lid once the clock changed to 12:26 and opened it after a second):

```
22/02/14 12:22:46,466 mds[61]: (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7fb94384fe00 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/firmwaresyncd.Tfyyuh
22/02/14 12:26:02,192 WindowServer[91]: _CGXSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius: Invalid window 0xffffffff
22/02/14 12:26:02,207 loginwindow[65]: find_shared_window: WID -1
22/02/14 12:26:02,208 loginwindow[65]: CGSGetWindowTags: Invalid window 0xffffffff
22/02/14 12:26:02,208 loginwindow[65]: find_shared_window: WID -1
22/02/14 12:26:02,208 loginwindow[65]: CGSSetWindowTags: Invalid window 0xffffffff
22/02/14 12:26:02,000 kernel[0]: Network delay is not specified! Defaulting to 0x384
22/02/14 12:26:02,000 kernel[0]: Network delay is not specified! Defaulting to 0x384
22/02/14 12:26:02,000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
22/02/14 12:26:02,000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
22/02/14 12:26:03,113 WindowServer[91]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "(PID 302)" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x11c03, PID 302)
22/02/14 12:26:03,113 WindowServer[91]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7f973844bc80(2000), shield 0x7f9738524d70(2001)
22/02/14 12:26:03,133 WindowServer[91]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7f973844bc80(2000), shield 0x7f9738524d70(2001)
22/02/14 12:26:04,000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
22/02/14 12:26:04,000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
22/02/14 12:26:04,764 WindowServer[91]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [445994346951]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
22/02/14 12:26:04,765 WindowServer[91]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
22/02/14 12:26:04,000 kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x9400 ****
22/02/14 12:26:21,985 loginwindow[65]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
22/02/14 12:26:27,283 loginwindow[65]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

**Update 3:**

With disabled bluetooth and wifi, the behaviour is a bit different. Now the screen stays totally black and isn't powered anymore (before it stayed "dark grey" == black but with backlight). Also in the console I can now read that an application was running while the laptop seemed to be unresponsive (I performed the experiment as soon as the clock showed 16:28).

```
22/02/14 16:28:01,966 xpcproxy[1371]: assertion failed: 13B42: xpcproxy + 3438 [EE7817B0-1FA1-3603-B88A-BD5E595DA86F]: 0x2
22/02/14 16:28:30,000 kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=1379[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allow (remove VALID)ing page
22/02/14 16:29:57,000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1393082997 0
22/02/14 16:30:00,000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

**Update 3.1:**

I've tried it one more time, this time it worked the first time as expected (close lid until the screen is turned off, open immediately after -> you see the login windows, everything is fine), and the second time I got again the same behaviour as described in **Update 3**, the console log (I tried to close is as soon as the clock showed 16:39 and I tried it immediately again after it worked for the first time):

```
22/02/14 16:38:38,694 Google Drive[284]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_WRITE] delete: "No such file or directory" - 0x2
22/02/14 16:39:02,790 WindowServer[106]: _CGXSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius: Invalid window 0xffffffff
22/02/14 16:39:02,817 loginwindow[72]: find_shared_window: WID -1
22/02/14 16:39:02,817 loginwindow[72]: CGSGetWindowTags: Invalid window 0xffffffff
22/02/14 16:39:02,817 loginwindow[72]: find_shared_window: WID -1
22/02/14 16:39:02,817 loginwindow[72]: CGSSetWindowTags: Invalid window 0xffffffff
22/02/14 16:39:02,000 kernel[0]: Network delay is not specified! Defaulting to 0x384
22/02/14 16:39:02,000 kernel[0]: Network delay is not specified! Defaulting to 0x384
22/02/14 16:44:27,000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1393083867 0
22/02/14 16:44:29,000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

Comment: It is not a bug, it starts writing a huge file capturing the status, so it can open with the same situation. So just give it time to do it. To test, try it without opening anything. To check for problems look in the Console at the timestamp of closing the lid and opening it.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I've tried it out, right after a fresh start and the result was the same. Any idea what I could/should look in the Console for?

Comment: Please publish the Console but only a few lines around the sleep and wake time stamp, maybe there is something going on.

Comment: Also would like to know your hardware, including the RAM load.

Comment: I've added the information in **Update 2**

Comment: Thanks for the update...I see Network issues??, disable all internet, wifi, network connections and try again without being connected to the network.

Comment: Thanks for staying with me so long. Disabling the network connection really did make a tiny change (**Update 3**) and it even worked once (**Update 3.1**)

Comment: Well, at least we are getting somewhere even if it is a tough one. Since you are now on the right path I leave you the fun part in finishing it.

Comment: FYI - after the latest Mac OS X update the issue seems to be fixed also with WiFi and Bluetooth being turned on, thx

Comment: Great :) make that in to your answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed with the Mac OS X update `10.9.2` from 26th of February.

For details on looking for a solution you can read the comments to my question.